# MS Word mail merge, multiple columns into rows, dynamic table

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

im creating a invoice template for mail merge using Word. In my source excel sheet, each row represent different invoice, but each invoice can have one or two items. I want to list this items in dynamic table inside my Word document. So if particular invoice has one item, i want the table to have one row, if the invoice have two items i want the table to have two rows. Columns in my source excel are: InvoiceNumber, Date, InvoiceItem1Value, InvoiceItem2Value. So the last two columns represents my invoice items, if they are both filled, then the table in my output document will have 2 rows, each containing one of the value. If only one column will be filled, then the output table will have only one row with a value from that filled column. Can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeking is a Many-to-one mail merge.  Mail merge wizard by default performs one-to-one mail merge i.e. it creates one document for each row in Excel. In your case if an invoice has two items, it will create two documents.

If you are looking for an online many-to-one mail merge, try [EDocGen](http://www.edocgen.com). If your organization is less rigid with security, you may also try add-ins from Graham Mayor and Doug Robbins. Incidentally, I published a blog for [many-to-one mail merge](http://www.edocgen.com/blogs/many-to-one-mail-merge) few weeks back with a similar use case.